# Continuously save data

Tags: c#

I've got an object moving around space over time and I want to save it's position (x, y, z) every 0.5s for a total of 10s. The object will be continuously moving but I only want it's latest 10s.

I've been thinking about using an array[20] but that would mean that every 0.5s I have to pop the last element (say data[19]), push every single one before and add the current one at data[0].

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Edit: performance might be an issue since I'll be saving a lot of these object's data. That's why I'm looking for a smart way to do that. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Keyword for research: circular buffer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. The c# queue http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue might be what I want

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, you can use a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Here's a sample implementation.

```
/// <summary>
/// A circular buffer with a maximum capacity set at construction time.
/// You can repeatedly add elements to this buffer; once it has reached its capacity
/// the oldest elements in it will be overwritten with the newly added ones.
/// This is how it differs from a queue: Oldest elements will be overwritten when the buffer is full.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements stored in the buffer.</typeparam>

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1710:IdentifiersShouldHaveCorrectSuffix", Justification = "Calling this CircularBufferCollection would be stupid.")]

public class CircularBuffer<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">The maximum capacity of the buffer.</param>

    public CircularBuffer(int capacity)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(capacity > 0, "Capacity must be greater than zero.");

        // We will use a buffer with a size one greater than the capacity.
        // The reason for this is to simplify the logic - we can use "front == back" to indicate an empty buffer.

        _buffer = new T[capacity+1];
    }

    /// <summary>The buffer capacity.</summary>

    public int Capacity
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
            return _buffer.Length - 1;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>The number of elements currently stored in the buffer.</summary>

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(0 <= Contract.Result<int>() && Contract.Result<int>() <= this.Capacity);

            int result = _back - _front;

            if (result < 0)
            {
                result += _buffer.Length;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Is the buffer empty?</summary>

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Count == 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Is the buffer full? (i.e. has it reached its capacity?)</summary>

    public bool IsFull
    {
        get
        {
            return nextSlot(_back) == _front;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Empties the buffer.</summary>

    public void Empty()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(this.IsEmpty);

        _front = _back = 0;
        Array.Clear(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length); // Destroy any old references so they can be GCed.
    }

    /// <summary>Add an element to the buffer, overwriting the oldest element if the buffer is full.</summary>
    /// <param name="newItem">The element to add.</param>

    public void Add(T newItem)
    {
        _buffer[_back] = newItem;
        _back = nextSlot(_back);

        if (_back == _front) // Buffer is full?
        {
            _front = nextSlot(_front); // Bump the front, overwriting the current front.
            _buffer[_back] = default(T); // Remove the old front value.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Removes and returns the oldest element from the buffer.</summary>
    /// <returns>The element that was removed from the buffer.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the buffer is empty.</exception>

    public T RemoveOldestElement()
    {
        Contract.Requires<InvalidOperationException>(!this.IsEmpty, "Cannot remove an element from an empty buffer.");

        T result = _buffer[_front];
        _buffer[_front] = default(T); // Zap the front element.
        _front = nextSlot(_front);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The typesafe enumerator. Elements are returned in oldest to newest order.
    /// This is not threadsafe, so if you are enumerating the buffer while another thread is changing it you will run
    /// into threading problems. Therefore you must use your own locking scheme to avoid the problem.
    /// </summary>

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = _front; i != _back; i = nextSlot(i))
        {
            yield return _buffer[i];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>The non-typesafe enumerator.</summary>

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(); // Implement in terms of the typesafe enumerator.
    }
    /// <summary>Calculates the index of the slot following the specified one, wrapping if necessary.</summary>

    private int nextSlot(int slot)
    {
        return (slot + 1) % _buffer.Length;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The index of the element at the front of the buffer. 
    /// If this equals _back, the buffer is empty.
    /// </summary>

    private int _front;

    /// <summary>
    /// The index of the first element BEYOND the last used element of the buffer. 
    /// Therefore this indicates where the next added element will go.
    /// </summary>

    private int _back;

    /// <summary>The underlying buffer. This has a length one greater than the actual capacity.</summary>

    private readonly T[] _buffer;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that this `GetEnumerator` implementation is not modification-safe. _If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an InvalidOperationException._ https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms says, you are looking for a circular buffer.

You can build it from a [linked list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) or a [queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx). The idea is that you add new elements at the end of the list and if the maximum size is reached, you remove the first elements.

You also can build it from an array. The idea is to have two index for the start and the end of the list and you go through the array by making a loop (use of modulo). Also when `startIndex == endIndex` you will not know if your list is empty or full so you will have to use a boolean to know this. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) speak a lot about it.

This last one is generally preferred because you will use the same place to store your objects. Although in C# it's only references that are stored and they do not take up so much space.

Google will give you a lot of implementation of this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If used it to keep track of the x latest events. `Enqueue()` every event and then `Dequeue()` until the `Queue` contains the number of events you want to keep.